# How to round the newly calculated value?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT product_c, description, cost,    
CASE WHEN product_no < 9 THEN cost * 1.10
     WHEN product_no BETWEEN 10 AND 15 THEN cost * 1.20
     WHEN product_no BETWEEN 15 AND 20 THEN cost * 1.25
     WHEN product_no > 20 THEN cost * 1.30
     END AS "New Cost"
     FROM table
WHERE "New Cost" > 19
```

I don't know where to place `ROUND()` so that it can round my "New Cost" column to have nearest hundred or 2 decimal like 100.53.
How do I use alias column to sort out products that are greater than 19?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the entire `case` inside the function call.  I would use `cast()` instead:

```
SELECT product_c, description, cost,    
       CAST((CASE WHEN product_no < 9 THEN cost * 1.10
                  WHEN product_no BETWEEN 10 AND 15 THEN cost * 1.20
                  WHEN product_no BETWEEN 15 AND 20 THEN cost * 1.25
                  WHEN product_no > 20 THEN cost * 1.30
             END) as DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS "New Cost"
FROM table
WHERE "New Cost" > 19
```

This is the same idea as `round()`, but it uses only the appropriate number of decimal places to store the result.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the drawback to simply using `round(..., 2)`? The OP didn't mention storing, but even then, a rounded number will have just two decimals, and if it is stored as NUMBER, then only enough storage room is used for two decimal places.

Comment: @mathguy . . . `round()` does round the value but it doesn't change the underlying data type.  Many query applications will still show an arbitrary number of decimal points.

Comment: I see - so the benefit is not if one stays strictly within Oracle and its SQL, but if the data is exchanged with applications. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two questions. The one in the title is easy:

```
SELECT ..., cost,
    round ( CASE WHEN .....
            ....END, 2) as "New Cost" ....
```

That is, the `round()` function has the form `round(expr, 2)` (if you want to round to two decimal places), and `expr` is your entire `CASE` expression - ALL of it, starting from the word `CASE` all the way to and including the word `END`.

This works exactly the same for any function and any expression - the expression can be, in particular, a `CASE` expression, and it (ALL of it) goes where any other expression (like a literal, or a column name) could go.

The other question you are asking has the answer "YOU CAN'T DO THAT".

You want to define "New Cost" through a computation in the SELECT clause, and you want to filter by "New Cost" in the WHERE clause. That is not how SELECT statements are processed.

In a SELECT statement, first the tables, views etc. (row sources) are identified. Joins / join conditions and WHERE conditions are applied next. Only after that (AFTER the WHERE conditions were applied), if there is no GROUP BY, does the processing go to the SELECT clause. What you define in the SELECT clause for the first time cannot be used in WHERE (or in HAVING, if you have a GROUP BY clause). If you are going to work with databases, it is exceptionally important to understand the order of processing of different parts of SQL statements.

To solve your problem, you need to put everything in a subquery; then in an outer query, you select *whatever* `WHERE "New Cost" > 19`.

By the way, there is very rarely a need to use quoted column names. Get in the habit of using names like new_cost (or New_Cost or NEW_COST - without the double quotes, Oracle doesn't care, it will save them in all caps but you can refer to them in any capitalization you like). And I assume you don't really have a table named `table`.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT product_c, description, cost,  new_cost
FROM   ( SELECT product_c, description, cost, 
                ROUND( CASE WHEN product_no < 9 THEN cost * 1.10
                            WHEN product_no BETWEEN 10 AND 15 THEN cost * 1.20
                            WHEN product_no BETWEEN 15 AND 20 THEN cost * 1.25
                            WHEN product_no > 20 THEN cost * 1.30
                            END , 2 ) AS new_cost
         FROM table_A
       )
WHERE new_cost > 19
;
```